# Applescript to read facebook notifications

Tags: applescript, notifications, facebook

I am very new to applescript as well as programming. I am trying to find a way for applescript to access my facebook unread notifications and whatsapp web unread chats and read it out to me.

I can use applescript to access mail or other mac apblications am facing difficulty with accessing the notifications and chats in google chrome browser. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript is built by Apple, for Apple (though unfortunately support has steadily declined since the move from 10.6.8 to 10.7)

While it is possible to do what you describe with AppleScript (or any language, with enough blood, sweat, tears, and coffee), it will be much more difficult than using Facebook's [API](https://developers.facebook.com) to view your notifications (or using OS X's built-in Facebook plugin).

As far as scripting Chrome with AppleScript, Safari will be easier as it has some built-in [hooks](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/18.html). I'd start with something to download a YouTube video (non-copyrighted, of course) using Safari, else you may get bogged down in authentication and trying to parse HTML, rather than actually having fun coding.